# cookies get deleted on browser restart

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cookies, jwt

I have users login info stored on MongoDB. When a user tries to log in, I get the user's supplied login credential and search the database if the user exits and sign them in. This process works. The problem is, I use JWT to generate a token and save it on the users cookies. All works fine until the browser is restarted, it loses the cookie and user needs to sign in again. Did I miss any step when saving the cookies? I gave it an expiry date of 10 years (for testing) so the cookies shouldn't have disappeared on restart. Where did I go wrong?

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const Users = require('../models/users')
require("dotenv").config();

const login = async(req, res) => {
  const {
    phoneNumber,
    password
  } = req.body;
  if (!phoneNumber || !password) return res.json({
    status: 'error',
    error: 'Please enter all fields'
  })
  else {
    Users.find({
        "phoneNumber": phoneNumber
      })
      .then(async(result) => {
        if (result.length > 0) {
          if (!await bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password)) {
            return res.json({
              status: 'error',
              error: 'Incorrect phone number or password'
            })
          } else {
            const token = jwt.sign({
              id: result[0].id
            }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
              expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES
            })
            const cookieOption = {
              expiresIn: new Date(Number(new Date()) + 315360000000),
              httpOnly: true
            }
            res.cookie('userRegistered', token, cookieOption)
          }
        } else {
          return res.json({
            status: 'error',
            error: 'Incorrect phone number or password'
          })
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
}

module.exports = login;
```

Answer (score 0):

this line in your code, do not send the result to the client automatically.

```
res.cookie('userRegistered', token, cookieOption)
```

you should write something like

```
res.cookie('userRegistered', token, cookieOption).json({
    status: 'OK'
});
```